# How to pass one argument into multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I want my bash script to process one or multiple attachments. They're passed to the script by the following parameter:

```
--attachment "filename(1),pathtofile(1),fileextension(1);[...];filename(n),pathtofile(n),fileextesion(n)"
--attachment "hello,/dir/hello.pdf,pdf;image,/dir/image.png,png"
```

This argument is stored in `inputAttachments`.

How can I store them in the following array?

```
attachmentFilename=("hello" "image")
attachmentPath=("/dir/hello.pdf" "/dir/image.png")
attachmentType=("pdf" "png")
```

My thought: I need to seperate `inputAttachments` at every semicolon and split those parts again at the comma. But how is this done and passed into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, how you are capturing the string after `--attachment` argument. But once you have it in a shell variable, all you need is a two-pass split which you can accomplish in the `bash` shell using `read` and a custom de-limiter to split on by setting the `IFS` value

```
IFS=\; read -r -a attachments <<<"hello,/dir/hello.pdf,pdf;image,/dir/image.png,png"
```

With this the string is split on `;` and stored in the array `attachments` as individual elements which you can visualize by doing `declare -p` on the array name

```
declare -p attachments
declare -a attachments='([0]="hello,/dir/hello.pdf,pdf" [1]="image,/dir/image.png,png")'
```

Now loop over the array and re-split the elements on `,` and append to individual arrays

```
for attachment in "${attachments[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read -r name path type <<<"$attachment"
    attachmentFilename+=( "$name" )
    attachmentPath+=( "$path" )
    attachmentType+=( "$type" )
done
```